# Generating pdfs with pdflib all images are blurry

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, pdflib

we are currently working on a PHP project for one of our customers where we had to increase the PHP version (5.6.40) and the version of PDFLIB (9.1.1.p3). Since then we have the problem that all images are blurred, as if there is a white veil over them. We don't understand what the reason can be, because there have been no changes in the code.
before update
[image]

after Update

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the pictures, two possible causes come to mind:

- The colour profile in the image is sometimes processed and sometimes not.
- an intermediate step processes the images before they are loaded and that has also changed.

It would also be good to know which PDFlib version you used before and whether the image is also manipulated on the server.

Probably the best thing to do is to open a support case directly with PDFlib support. https://www.pdflib.com/licensing-support/opening-a-support-case/

Then you can also send more details and an example PDF before and after the update. It is also best to share an example input image.

Comment: Hi Rainer you nailed it. Some of the images have the color profile SWOP (Coated). Does you know if PDFlib supports this color profile?

Comment: PDFlib has been supporting ICC profiles (ICC version 2.x or 4.x) included in images for many years, no matter which ones they are, they just have to valid and match the color space of the image. Thus I do not suspect that the problem can be traced back to this. But of course I don't know which PDFlib version you used to use.